# python dictionary weird behavior with dict as container

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Here is a simplified code snippet of the problem

```
>>> dict ({'A': 58, 'B': 130} for _ in range(1))
{'A': 'B'}
```

I am expecting it to return the same dictionary passed in.

if I do

```
>>> dict({'A': 58, 'B': 130})
```

I get exactly what I am looking for, that is 
`{'A': 58, 'B': 130}`

Why is this behavior different, how to fix it?
I cannot alter the expression there, but I can alter the input dictionary in whatever way I like, for example, I can pass it like [`{'A': 58, 'B': 130}]`

Comment: Re: "fix it": I don't see how this is possible (at least, without a lot of hackery). You are initializing your dict with a iterable (more precisely, a generator) with length 1, so the resulting dictionary will have 1 item, not 2.

Comment: Why do you say "I cannot alter the expression there, but I can alter the input dictionary in whatever way I like"? Is this some sort of hacker puzzle? Give us the exact stipulation and we might be able to find a way. (For example, if you just need any string there, `dict(item for item in {'A': 58, 'B': 130}.items() for _ in range(1))` will work.)

Comment: Are you able to alter the dict initializer?  `dict ({'A': 58, 'B': 130} for _ in range(1)[0])`

Comment: @ImperishableNight the expression is part of a python library/module which I cannot alter. the exact expression comes in to play is "func1 (func2 for _ in range(1))". func1 is a container which in my case is dict and func2 returns another dict as above.

Comment: Do you mean `func2` or `func2()`? As written, this line of code won't even call `func2`.

Comment: Also can you alter `func1`?

Comment: I am curious why this library/module does it this way, though. It seems like it really doesn't want to return a container with length longer than 1.

Comment: @ImperishableNight `func2() `, it returns a dict() which is what given in the code snippet. The library has an elaborate framework for generator with container registration with hooks of `func1 and func2`. Yes, I can alter `func1`, and yes I know i can write a custom logic for `func1` and get away with that.

Comment: Maybe it *wants* you to alter `func1`. The `for _ in range(1)` seems like a mechanic to give `func1` the freedom whether to call `func2`, rather than an attempt to generate the actual elements of the container. Again, without a name for said library I can only guess.

Comment: @ImperishableNight this is DEAP python library. Its a genetic algo implementation. I have some special use case.

Comment: Can you pinpoint the exact file and line in github? I think special use cases call for special treatments like altering `func1`, or even patching the library itself. If you think your use case might not be that rare, consider opening an issue, too.

Comment: @ImperishableNight Here is the code: look at line 23 in initRepeat() [https://github.com/DEAP/deap/blob/master/deap/tools/init.py]

Comment: anyway, I worked it around for now with a list instead of dict, but I had to hack rest of my code to get actual element like `li[0]['dict_key']` which is what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: Is it possible to change `n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{'A': 58, 'B': 130} for _ in range(1)` yields `[{'A': 58, 'B': 130}]`, therefore you are passing a list, not a dict, to `dict()`.

According to the documentation, if you pass an iterable to `dict()`, you effectively get:

```
d = {}
for k, v in iterable:
   d[k] = v
```

Since the dict inside the list has exactly two elements, the `for k,v in iterable:` loop gets the first two keys in the dict.  If the dict had only one element, or more than two, you would get a `ValueError`.

Comment: I get your point, but what I don't understand is - how is a simple iteration on a list yeilding inner elements. What I am expecting from iter of `[{'A': 58, 'B': 130}]` is `{'A': 58, 'B': 130}` which is the `list[0]` element. Not something inside that. What is wrong here?

Comment: `for k,v in iterable` takes each value in `iterable` and then iterates over _that_ to extract `k` and `v`. In your example `iterable` is a list containing one dict. Iterating over a dict yields keys, so `k` and `v` become `'A'` and `'B'`.

Answer (score 5):

A dict can be initialized with another dict, or with an iterable of pairs, which is what you have given it. Note that iterating over a dict yields its keys only.

```
>>> d = {'A': 58, 'B': 130}
>>> list(d)
['A', 'B']
>>> dict([('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D')])
{'A': 'B', 'C': 'D'}
>>> dict([d, ('C', 'D')])
{'A': 'B', 'C': 'D'}
```

Python is behaving exactly as specified. Your dict happens to be a pair.

Answer (score 2):

There's something special about the dict you're passing... `({'A': 58, 'B': 130} for _ in range(1))` represents a generator sequence of length 1. What you  are passing is similar to

```
dict([{'A': 58, 'B': 130}])
# {'A': 'B'}
```

These, on the other hand, will not work:

```
dict([{'A':58}])
# ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

dict([{'A':58, 'B': 130, 'C': 150}])    
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required
```

The first example worked because your dictionary had ***exactly two entries***.

The sequence is passed to the `dict` method, which takes the two items it needs to create a key-value pair, and creates a dictionary like this:

```
{'A': 'B'}
```

**IOW, it requires an iterable of pairs, which is what your sequence with a single dict of two entries is. Anything else will throw a `ValueError`.**

Answer (score 1):

Because it simply will make it `['A', 'B']`, with `list` as well:

```
>>> list({'A': 58, 'B': 130})
['A', 'B']
>>>
```

And since it iterates in `dict` since it's a list of dictionaries, it would make it `list` for all of them, so:

```
>>> dict([{'A': 58, 'B': 130}])
{'A': 'B'}
>>> dict({'A': 58, 'B': 130})
{'A': 58, 'B': 130}
>>>
```

Also, without `dict` it would be doing something like the below for a list of dictionaries:

```
>>> {*{'A': 58, 'B': 130}}
{'A', 'B'}
>>>
```

Just in a dictionary-like way, but you should get it now.

Comment: what I don't understand here is how is an simple iteration on a list yeilding inner elements. What I am expecting from iter of `[{'A': 58, 'B': 130}]` is `{'A': 58, 'B': 130}` which is the `list[0]` element. Not something inside that. What is wrong here?

Comment: @joe To get the first one do: `dict([{'A': 58, 'B': 130}][0])`